# Postgres column contains string values which need to pivoted

Tags: string, postgresql, pivot

details column has string data in the following format (enclosed by parenthesis as shown) -

```
{"id":"350876","Time":"Aug 22 2022, 12:41:57 PM" ,"Session":"NO","teamPercentage":89}
```

how do I add these id , Time, Session , teamPercentage as new columns in the same row?

My thought process:
Do I need to do some pivot of some sort? But I don't know if pivot can be done with string values, and more specifically how to detect id, time, session etc. and pivot these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a JSON value, so just treat it as one. Then you can use the [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to extract the values for the keys

```
select details::json ->> 'id' as id,
       details::json ->> 'Time' as time,
       details::json ->> 'Session' as session,
       details::json ->> 'teampPercentage' as percentage
from the_table;
```

Comment: varchar(255) is the column data type. this is not json right?

Comment: But the _content_ is JSON, and to use the JSON function, you need to cast the value to a JSON value, that's what `::json` does.

Comment: SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
  Detail: Token "User" is invalid.
  Where: JSON data, line 1: User...

Comment: i get the following error when i try the code

Comment: sorry I was doing something wrong, your code works!